# How to generate fixed random numbers from a given range that yields same output in each execution

Tags: python, random, pycharm

```
for x in range(16):
    ran.append(random.randint(1, 500))
    # print(ran)
```

Generating random numbers within a range is easy but how to generate random numbers from a given range that yields the same output in each execution for that particular range in python.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you [`seed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) your `random` with the same seed, you'll get the same series of values:

```
random.seed(7) # Or any other arbitrary seed

for x in range(16):
    ran.append(random.randint(1, 500))
```

Answer (score 0):

In random number generators there is usually a `seed()` function that does that. If the argument to seed is constant, the generated sequence of numbers will be the same. So, just write `random.seed(some_number)` in the beginning of your code.